# Roots of function over a certain interval

Tags: functions, roots

Suppose we have a polynomial of degree $n$. For $n\geq 5$, there is not solution equation. However, I am wondering if it is possible to derive some information about the roots over a specific interval. For instance, I have the following system of equations: 
$$\frac{(1-x-2y)(2-2x-y)^2}{27x^3}-1=0$$
$$\frac{(1-x-2y)^2(2-2x-y)}{27y^3}-1=0$$
Here, I could simply use Cardano's method, or approximate an answer with Newton's method. However, I would like to simplify the equation further with the information that all variables ($x$ and $y$ in this case) are restricted to the interval $[0,1]$. Is there any way to do this? Does the interval ever provide information in a general case? 
Here is a general form of the function: 
$$\frac{\big(1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}nx_n\big)\big(n-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(n+1-i)x_n\big)^n}{((n+1)x)^{n+1}}=1$$

EDIT: To make the question a bit more specific, here is the kind of argument I want to propose. If we take all the variables to be in the interval $[0,1]$, then can we say that because of the sign changes of the derivative in that interval, it can only have a certain amount of roots in that interval? i.e. if $\nabla f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)<0$ for all $x_1,x_2,...,x_n\in[0,1]$, can we say that $f$ only has one root in $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sturm sequences to count the number of real roots of a polynomial (in one variable) in a given interval.  Things are a bit more complicated with several variables, but we can try eliminating variables.

In your example, according to Maple the resultant of $(1-x-2y)(2-2x-y)^2 - 27x^3$ and 
$(1-x-2y)^2(2-2x-y)-27y^3$ with respect to $y$ is 
$$-691896816\,{x}^{9}+399171240\,{x}^{8}-658337301\,{x}^{7}+685401426\,{
x}^{6}-533980107\,{x}^{5}+308826270\,{x}^{4}-130832901\,{x}^{3}+
45349632\,{x}^{2}-11337408\,x+1259712
$$

Using the Sturm method, this has exactly one root in the interval $[0,1]$.
It turns out to be approximately $0.2769531794$.
Similarly, the resultant with respect to $x$ is
$$ 691896816\,{y}^{9}-399171240\,{y}^{8}+481780791\,{y}^{7}-453811248\,{y
}^{6}+317624571\,{y}^{5}-144551952\,{y}^{4}+48124935\,{y}^{3}-12400290
\,{y}^{2}+2125764\,y-157464
$$
which also has one root in the interval $[0,1]$, approximately $0.1820408003$.  Now it's not automatic that the $y$ value for $x\approx0.2769531794$ is approximately $0.1820408003$ (maybe there 
is one solution with $x$ in the interval and $y$ outside, and another with $y$ in the interval and $x$ outside), but in fact it turns out that 
these roots are the only real roots of those resultants.

Comment: So would this method not work for greater than $2$ variables?